# Does Markov Chain converge in Variance Norm?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Assume the chain $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on the statespace $(S,\mathcal{F})$ is aperiodic, irreducible and additionally positive recurrent. We denote with $\pi$ its (unique) stationary distribution. Is it true that for any $x\in S$ $$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}~\underset{\text{A}\in\mathcal{F}^{\mathbb{Z}_+}}{\text{sup}}~|P_x((X_{n},X_{n+1},\dots)\in\text{A})-P_\pi(X\in A)| =0?$$

I would assume this is true since as a positive recurrent chain it keeps hitting again and again also in its asymptotics. But I can't figure out how to prove it. I tried to come up with any clever coupling which seems to be the way to deal with those Variance norms (see Durrett Chapter 6, Convergence Theorem).

Comment: @ MathProb This is appearing on my HW right now, haha.  I've tried induction--- using the convergence theorem as the base case... But I couldn't figure out the induction step. Please help if you've figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By Markov property, conditioning on $X_n$ and shifting by n steps,  $$P_x((X_n,X_{n+1}, ...)\in A) = \sum_{i}P_i(X\in A)P_{X_n}(i)$$, where $P_{X_n}$ is the distribution of $X_n$.

Since $$P_\pi(X\in A) = \sum_{i}P_i(X\in A)\pi(i)$$, we have
$$|P_x((X_n,X_{n+1}, ...)\in A)-P_\pi(X\in A)|
\le \sum_{i}|P_{X_n}(i)-\pi(i)|
=||P_{X_n}-\pi||_1
\rightarrow 0$$