# Proof of aperiodic Markov Convergence Theorem for null recurrent case.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

**Status quo:**
We consider a irreducible, aperiodic Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on a countable set $S$ with tranistion function $p(\cdot,\cdot)$.

Now we want to examine $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}~p^n(i,j)$ for arbitrary $i,j\in S$.

If $j$ is **transient**  we can show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n(i,j)<\infty$ and therefore we know that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}~p^n(i,j)=0$.  If $j$ is **positive recurrent** we can show by nice coupling argument (see for example Durrett) that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}~p^n(i,j)=\pi(j)$, where $\pi$ is the unique stationary distribution of the chain.

**The question:**
My concern is the **null recurrent** case. I looked through a bunch of textbooks and I could not find a proof for the fact that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}~p^n(i,j)=0$ in this case. Most textbooks mention it but none of them gives a proof and I can't proof it either.
Any ideas, thoughts and especially references are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ?? Huh? Which textbooks did you check?

Comment: @Did The usual suspects (Durrett, Klenke, Levin, lecturenotes) - maybe I was blind. But now I found it (see my answer).

Comment: @Did Another thing since you have always been a help with my probability questions. Any thoughts on this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184926/does-markov-chain-converge-in-variance-norm ? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I found a nice answer in the [book by Norris](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s18.pdf) Theorem 1.8.5. It also makes use of a Coupling argument with the choice of a shifted measure.